# How to install Couchbase onto a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, software-installation, database

I am making a discord bot, and I want to use Couchbase as my Database option. (So I can get some practise on it, since work is switching to it)

However, Couchbase does not officially target the ARM platform, but I have heard of people getting it to work on a PI.

So how can I get my Couchbase to work with the Pi?

Comment: Are you referring to Couchbase Lite?

Comment: There's a few blog posts about it that are a little old, so they were written with older versions of Couchbase Lite in mind, but still might be a good starting point: https://blog.couchbase.com/collecting-ibeacon-data-with-couchbase-and-raspberry-pi-iot-devices/ and https://borrrden.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/couchbase-lite-on-raspberry-pi/